# Javascript : error in forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to perform a simple forEach loop .

```
if (this.list.length == 0) {
    this.list.push({ name, price, familly, quantity })
} else {
    this.list_achat.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.name === name && element.familly === familly) {
            element.quantity += quantity
        } else {
            this.list.push({ name, price, familly, quantity })
        }
        this.prix_totale += element.quantity * element.price
    })
}
```

When I add first a product to add in list_achat when list_achat.length == 0, but when i add another product that what will happen

```
[
  {"name":"prod1","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":"4"},
  {"name":"prod2","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":"3"},
  {"name":"prod2","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":"2"},
  {"name":"prod2","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":1}
]
```

i want to keep only

```
[
  {"name":"prod1","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":"4"},
  {"name":"prod2","price":"10","familly":"famille1","quantity":"3"}
]
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code readably and consistently. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding to the array **each time** the `forEach` callback is called (which is for every element).

You're probably looking for `Array.prototype.find`, which returns the first element in the array for which the callback returns a truthy value (or `undefined` if not found):

```
const entry = this.list.find(e => e.name == name && e.familly == familly);
if (!entry) {
    this.list.push({name,price,familly,quantity})
} else {
    entry.quantity +=  quantity;
}
```

Comment: Wow !!! Thank you some much !!! and sorry for the presentation of my code